# why does an image of size 9 MB on disk occupy 125 MB in RAM when loaded into numpy?

Tags: python, image, numpy, opencv, scikit-image

[Link to the image in question](https://github.com/thalishsajeed/PythonLearn/raw/master/Houston_Chronicle__May_19_2018_51.jpg)

Let me reproduce the issue I'm facing.

```
from skimage import io
image = io.imread("https://github.com/thalishsajeed/PythonLearn/raw/master/Houston_Chronicle__May_19_2018_51.jpg")
print((image.nbytes/(1024*1024)))
```

Result: `125.87553691864014`

So how is it that a `9.45 MB` file blows upto `125 MB` when loaded into a numpy array using skimage? (I was able to replicate same results using openCV's `cv2.imread` function as well)

I guess this has something to do with JPEG compression, however if anyone can provide a more detailed explanation i'd really appreciate it.

Comment: check this [Q&A](https://superuser.com/questions/1004329/why-is-image-size-and-the-memory-required-to-display-it-different)

Answer (score 4):

Because that is a JPG image file, which is a compressed image format. Your image resolution is 6633x6633 and it is a color image. Meaning that:
Number of pixels = 6633 * 6633
Total byte size = 6633 * 6633 * 3 (RGB, each color pixel is 1 byte)
~125 mb

Comment: @Mad Physicist There's lots of areas of solid colour in the image, so the high compression is not surprising. In those areas 63 of the 64 DCT coefficients will be zero.